# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Time out

Tags: github

When try to clone a project using the `git clone` command I got this following error message.

```
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Time out
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I think something is wrong with github servers

Comment: Yes I found this a DDoS attack. https://status.github.com/

Comment: Same problem here
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxx.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893178/failed-to-connect-to-github-com-port-443-connection-timed-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDoS attack check this link https://status.github.com/

**The connectivity problems have been identified as a DDoS attack. We're working to mitigate now.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have used

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:**yourname**/learngit.git
```

to connect your local repository to github.

**If you find the following  error:**

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

Then write the following statement in your git bash.

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

then write again to re-connect your repository to GitHub.

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:**yourname**/learngit.git
```

If the above steps can not help you, there must be some ssh errors I think.