# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: github, raspberry-pi, failed-to-connect

I have a project on a raspberry pi and am maintaining using github. All has been working fine until today when I got the message:

```
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Tried switching off and on again and several other troubleshooting, no problems with internet connections. Searching online comes up with people using proxies or firewalls which I am not using or at least they haven't made an effect until now.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if the issue persists: there is an incident on GitHub side which just got resolved.

"[Incident on 2020-05-19 14:04 UTC](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/6hjb1189t0y9)"

> investigating reports of service interruptions impacting GitHub.com services

If it was working before and you did not change anything, it could resume working again.